# (py)Spark job fails on concatenating strings

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a 2TB memory cluster and a 1TB dataset (on disk). The task is to join user sessions together for further analysis. The (slightly simplified) code is as follows:

```
dataset.flatMap(
  get_key_val_from_json  # gives (key, [json_string])
).reduceByKey(
  add  # merge lists
).map(
  lambda x: Row(k=x[0], v='\t'.join(x[1]))  # convert the list to a string
).toDF(
  ['key', 'events_with_tab_sep']  # convert to DataFrame so could save as parquet
).write.mode(
  'overwrite'
).parquet(
  some_path
)
```

However, at the `reduceByKey` step the job could not proceed as executors start to fail (showing a lot of CANNOT FIND ADDRESS errors) and restart. The job eventually throws an error message of

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.

because

> Job X couldn't finish because Stage Y has failed 4 times.

It seems an OOM issue in the shuffle process in `reduceByKey`? However, I consider this task to be not-memory-related if I extract, sort, and reduce. Does Spark need to load the whole dataset into memory for reduce operations?

**Tried but didn't work**

1- To ask Spark to persist the intermediary files to local disk only, i.e.,

```
extracted = dataset.flatMap(
  get_key_val_from_json
).persist(
    StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY
)

extracted.reduceByKey(
  add
).map(
  lambda x: Row(k=x[0], v='\t'.join(x[1]))
).toDF(
  ['key', 'events_with_tab_sep']
).write.mode(
  'overwrite'
).parquet(
  some_path
)
```

Comment: Well, you apply non reducing operation in `reduceByKey` which is pretty much Yet Another `groupByKey`. In the worst case scenario this can work only if all data fits in the memory allocated for a single executor.

Comment: I understand the worst case would be all 1TB data having the same key. Here I know the longest list of events is around 100KB, so concatenating them shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I'm confused that if there is a `sort` after the first `map`, the `reduceByKey` action doesn't need to depend on the full-dataset-in-memory. But it doesn't seem the case.

Comment: A good discussion on this problem is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36376369/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-do-a-sorted-reduce-in-pyspark)

Answer (score 0):

Well first you could perform tasks on seperate lines, with .first() or .show() steps in between, to see which one fails.

Comment: It is `reduceByKey` that fails. I'll make it more explicit.

Comment: `operator.add` from python